# Get confused about square brackets in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wildcard

as the [document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) describes,`[set]` in Bash can match any character in `set`,

in the following , I hava 3 dirs called a,b,c in current directory:

```
$ ls

a b c
```

$ ls [abd]   # just as expected,show dirs a and b
a:

b:

$ ls [bd]    # expecting show dir b but noting matched

$ ls [ad]    # expecting show dir a but noting matched

can someone explain this to me?thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct behavior.

```
ls [bd]
```

Prints files inside the directory `b` and that is empty.

To test further you can do:

```
touch b/foo
ls [bd]
```

Which will give output

```
foo
```

PS: However in your first command when you do `ls [abc]` there are **more than one matching directories in current path** `a` and `b` hence you get the output as shown in in your question.